# How to convert every noun in its singular/plural form in a pandas column which contains sentences based on which form is the most used

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dafaframe like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Comment': ['I love these boots', 'This dog is cute', 'Cool boot', 'This dog like these boots', 'Dogs are cute']})
```

Of course, my real dataframe has TONS of rows, and  the comments are completely randoms.

In a perfect world, I'd like to convert EVERY NOUN (only, so not verb etc.) in his singular/plural form based on which form is the most used. So the output I'd like would be :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Comment': ['I love these boots', 'This dog is cute', 'Cool boots', 'This dog like these boots', 'Dog are cute']})
```

If it's not possible (or too heavy) to do that, then I will still be happy if I can just singularize (or pluralize, whatever) every noun. It would not be perfect but it will be better than what I have right now.

Comment: English does not have consistent regular pluralisation (sheep/sheep; child/children, mouse/mice ...) and so this cannot be done in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

This is NLP territory! You'll need a language model to first identify what are the nouns, verbs etc. You could use spacy (https://spacy.io/) for this, for example.
This package has functions to do part-of-speech tagging (https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features). You could apply these functions to your pandas dataframe. Then, you could get the lemma of the nouns. This is the singular version of the noun.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already looked at that and looked at a lot of similar methods, but I’m struggling to code it. I’m still trying to make it work